# Phpstorm gist кракозябры

Tags: phpstorm

Подскажите, как в phpstorm настроить правильную кодировку в плагине gist, так как сейчас кракозябры. Если description гиста написано на русском, то вместо этого лезут эти некрасивые символы, как это исправить?
Только начал пользоваться phpstorm.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: UTF - 8 (наверное)

Comment: @СергейГрушин я спросил **как настроить**...

Answer (score 0):

Настроить 'encoding' можно попробовать в 'Settings' выполнив поиск по соответствующему параметру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению не помог этот способ.

Comment: @Владимир , не помог как ? старые названия так и остались не читаемыми. Или вы новую сделали, с предложеннными настройками и она тоже не читается ?